# Convert between str and int without using built-in typecasting

Tags: python, string, integer

## NB: You may not use built-in typecasting: code this yourself.

```
def str2int(s):
     result = 0
     if s[0] == '-':
         sign = -1
         i = 1
         while i < len(s):
             num = ord(s[i]) - ord('0')
             result = result * 10 + num
             i += 1
         result = sign * result
         return result
     else:
         i = 0
         while i < len(s):
             num = ord(s[i]) - ord('0')
             result = result * 10 + num
             i += 1
         return result
```

## NB: You may not use built-in str() or string template. Code this yourself.

```
def int2str(i):
    strng = ""
    if i > 0:
        while i != 0:
            num = i % 10
            strng += chr(48+num)
            i = i / 10
        return strng[::-1]
    else:
        while i != 0:
            num = abs(i) % 10
            strng += chr(48+num)
            i = abs(i) / 10
        return '-' + strng[::-1]
```

I am a newbie and I have to write code based on basic. I write these function by myself but these look weird. Can you help me to improve code? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This maybe a better question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.
Not withstanding there is no error checking, one obvious comment is you have common code that can be factored out. Only capture in the `if`, `else` what is unique rather than repeat the `while` loop:

```
def str2int(s):
     if s[0] == '-':
         sign = -1
         i = 1
     else:
         sign = 1
         i = 0
     result = 0
     while i < len(s):
         num = ord(s[i]) - ord('0')
         result = result * 10 + num
         i += 1
     return sign * result
```

It is generally considered better form in python to iterate over list rather than indices:

```
def str2int(s):
     sign = 1
     if s[0] == '-':
         sign = -1
         s = s[1:]

     result = 0
     for c in s:
         num = ord(c) - ord('0')
         result = result * 10 + num
     return sign * result
```

These last lines are equivalent to a standard `map` and `reduce` (`reduce` is in `functools` for py3). Though some would argue against it:

```
from functools import reduce  # Py3

def str2int(s):
     sign = 1
     if s[0] == '-':
         sign = -1
         s = s[1:]

     return sign * reduce(lambda x,y: x*10+y, map(lambda c: ord(c) - ord('0'), s))
```

There are similar opportunities to do the same for `int2str()`.